# Uploading array of images(wrapped in NSData) to the server in iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, http, nsurlconnection

Good day, 
I'm trying to upload an array of images to the server, images are wrapped into NSData, but the server returning only one image, this is my code:

```
- (void)actionSave{

NSArray *imagesArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSData dataWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.imageViewForImageOne.image)],
                        [NSData dataWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.imageViewForImageTwo.image)],
                        [NSData dataWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.imageViewForImageThree.image)],
                        [NSData dataWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.imageViewForImageFour.image)], nil];

NSData *images = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:imagesArray];

NSMutableURLRequest *requestImg = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@&mid=%@", SEND_POST_TO_WALL, [self.currentFriend objectForKey:@"uid"]]] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:60.0f];

[requestImg setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

NSString *boundary = @"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449";
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", boundary];
[requestImg addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

NSMutableData *postData = [NSMutableData dataWithCapacity:[images length] + 512];
[postData setData:images];

NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];

//Photo
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"image\"; filename=\"image.png\"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[@"Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:postData];
[body appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@--\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

//Text
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"text\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[self.textView.text dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[requestImg setHTTPBody:body];

NSURLConnection *connectionForImage = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:requestImg delegate:self];

if (connectionForImage) {
    self.infoData = [NSMutableData data];
} else {
    NSLog(@"Connection failed");
}
```

}

This is the result that server returns:

```
    array(3) {
  ["act"]=>
  string(12) "comments.add"
  ["module"]=>
  string(7) "account"
  ["mid"]=>
  string(4) "7728"
}
POST:

array(1) {
  ["text"]=>
  string(5) "Gjdgy"
}
FILES:

array(1) {
  ["image"]=>
  array(5) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(9) "image.png"
    ["type"]=>
    string(10) "image/jpeg"
    ["tmp_name"]=>
    string(14) "/tmp/php9oudKt"
    ["error"]=>
    int(0)
    ["size"]=>
    int(463652)
  }
}
```

What I'm doing wrong???

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't see any code to read the server response, and yet you say "server returning only one image".

Comment: Yes, server returning one images, but the script can handle two images, rigth now I would update the post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You showed us the POST of the data but not the GET of that data again, so not sure what you mean by "only returns one image". What its returning should be the exact same data blob you went up, which is the archive. You can test this by logging the size of what you send up with the size of what you get back - they should both be the same if the server is returning your original blob back (if its not, that's a web issue not an ios issue).

With the blob you get back from the web, you then need to NSKeyUnarchive it to get your original array of data items. The unraveling is the reverse of the raveling.